# Sharing Blogger blogs in Facebook

Tags: facebook, blogger

Facebook has a feature to share links. On the main homepage there is a Share Link tab at the top. You paste your link and can write some text that will be displayed above the shared link.

I noticed that when many other people share their links, they get some text from the article displayed next to the picture (in grey). However, when I share my Blogger blog, I just get the blog url (buczekmruczek.blogspot.com in this case). How can I get more content in there? Why url's shared by others get more information?

Answer (score 4):

Facebook automatically parses out some text it thinks is important from your website. Certain **[Open Graph Tags](http://ogp.me/)** are respected to figure out what content to show.

If you have control over the HTML on your blogspot website, **I recommend placing a few Open Graph tags to give some meta-data about your page**.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this feature has been recently implemented in Blogger, it is just turned off by default. For some reason the description is called "Search Preferences".

First you need to enable Search preferences for your blog, this is in the settings menu of your blog. There you type the text that will be the description of the whole blog.

Next, for every post, in the edit mode, there is a Search preferences option in the menu on the right hand side. Click on it, and voila: you can enter the description for the given post. These descriptions will automatically show up when you share your blog post in Facebook or Google+.

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the Search Preferences info and install Open Graph tags.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Could you give me some clues about what elaboration you think would be helpful?    I'm basically saying "do both of the actions suggested, not just one"

Comment: Like what is the Search Preferences info, and how do one install Open Graph tags